# Windows - My profile will not load correctly

Tags: windows, user-profiles

Every time I turn on my computer it says that it's creating a new desktop even though all of my files are still there under my user account.

I get this message every time I turn my computer on " you have been logged on with a temporary profile. Changes you make to this profile will be lost when you log off. Please see the events log for details."

Does any one know what I could do to try and fix this, why it may have happened because the last thing I did was have automatic updates and where I can Locate the event log.

Answer (score 1):

Go to control panel and create a new user account with a different name, log off the temp account and log into the new account you created and run a chkdsk on the C drive.

How to run Chkdsk - Graphical interface
Tick both boxes
http://vlaurie.com/computers2/Articles/chkdsk.htm

After the reboot and chkdsk is done, try to log into your old account, it it does not load, log into the new account and move your old profile to your new account and start using that account, use if for a week or so, when you are satisfied with the new account delete the old corrupt user account.

Scroll down to: "copying your user Profile in this article, it is for XP but is very similar process for Vista and W7 also.
http://www.lockergnome.com/it/2004/12/15/get-it-done-recover-a-damaged-windows-xp-user-profile/

.